# Partial specialization of member functions

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

I am having problems with a template specialization.  Below are two classes, AbstractSetting (parent) and Setting (child).  (AbstractSetting is probably not important, but I am including it for context.)

The ultimate goal of this code is to create a container to hold various INI settings of different types -- string, int, enum, etc. (DataType), that can be referenced with an enum (IndexType).  There may be different index enums in different contexts (main game, test suite, server, etc.).

I am trying to create a series of fromString methods that, when passed a string, return an object of DataType (one of my template parameters).

The code as presented will compile but not link.

If I uncomment the assert, it will link, but none of the specializations are called, and the assert trips on every call to fromString, regardless of the parameters.

How can I make this work?

Note that U32, S32, etc. are types of ints.

```
template <class IndexType>
class AbstractSetting
{
private:
   IndexType mName;     // Value we use to look this item up
   string mIniKey;      // INI key
   string mIniSection;  // INI section
   string mComment;

public:
   // Constructor
   AbstractSetting(IndexType name, const string &key, 
                   const string &section, const string &comment):
      mIniKey(key), 
      mIniSection(section), 
      mComment(comment)
   {
      mName = name;
   }

   ~AbstractSetting() { /* Do nothing */ }      // Destructor

   IndexType getName()    const { return mName; }
   string    getKey()     const { return mIniKey; }
   string    getSection() const { return mIniSection; }
   string    getComment() const { return mComment; }

   virtual void setValFromString(const string &value) = 0;

   virtual string getValueString() const = 0;         // Returns val as str
   virtual string getDefaultValueString() const = 0;  // Returns def val as str
};


////////////////////////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////

template <class DataType, class IndexType>
class Setting : public AbstractSetting<IndexType>
{
   typedef AbstractSetting Parent;

private:
   DataType mDefaultValue;
   DataType mValue;

public:
   Setting(IndexType name, const DataType &defaultValue, const string &iniKey, 
           const string &iniSection, const string &comment):
      Parent(name, iniKey, iniSection, comment),
      mDefaultValue(defaultValue),
      mValue(defaultValue)
   {
      // Do nothing
   }


   ~Setting() { /* Do nothing */ }

   // Templated declaration
   DataType fromString(const string &val) ; //{ Assert(false, "Specialize me!"); }

   // Specializations
   template<string *> string             
   fromString(const string &val) { return val; }

   template<S32 *> S32                
   fromString(const string &val) { return atoi(val.c_str()); }

   template<U32 *> 
   U32 fromString(const string &val) { return atoi(val.c_str()); }

   template<U16 *> 
   U16 fromString(const string &val) { return atoi(val.c_str()); }

   template<DisplayMode *> 
   DisplayMode fromString(const string &val) { return stringToDisplayMode(val); }

   template<YesNo *> 
   YesNo fromString(const string &val) { return stringToYesNo(val); }

   template<RelAbs *> 
   RelAbs fromString(const string &val) { return stringToRelAbs(val); }

   template<ColorEntryMode *> 
   ColorEntryMode fromString(const string &val) { return stringToColorEntryMode(val); }

   template<GoalZoneFlashStyle *> 
   GoalZoneFlashStyle fromString(const string &val) { return stringToGoalZoneFlashStyle(val); }

   template<Color *> 
   Color fromString(const string &val) { return Color::iniValToColor(val); }


   void   setValue(const DataType &value)       { mValue = value;                 }

   DataType getValue() const                    { return mValue;                  }
   string getValueString() const                { return toString(mValue);        }
   string getDefaultValueString() const         { return toString(mDefaultValue); }

   void   setValFromString(const string &value) { setValue(fromString(value));    }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution!

Since it seems that member functions cannot be partially specialized, I solved the problem by creating a new class that does not use the IndexType parameter.

```
class Evaluator
{
public:
  template <class DataType> DataType fromString(const string &val);
};
```

In the .cpp file, I added:

```
// Templated default - needs to be overriden
template<class DataType> DataType
Evaluator::fromString(const string &val) { 
    Assert(false, "Specialize me!"); 
    return DataType(); 
}

// Specializations.
// NOTE: All template specializations must be declared in the namespace scope to be
// C++ compliant.  Shame on Visual Studio!
template<> string             
Evaluator::fromString(const string &val) { return val; }

template<> S32                
Evaluator::fromString(const string &val) { return atoi(val.c_str()); }

template<> U32                
Evaluator::fromString(const string &val) { return atoi(val.c_str()); }

template<> U16                
Evaluator::fromString(const string &val) { return atoi(val.c_str()); }

template<> DisplayMode        
Evaluator::fromString(const string &val) { return stringToDisplayMode(val); }

template<> YesNo              
Evaluator::fromString(const string &val) { return stringToYesNo(val); }

template<> RelAbs             
Evaluator::fromString(const string &val) { return stringToRelAbs(val); }

template<> ColorEntryMode     
Evaluator::fromString(const string &val) { return stringToColorEntryMode(val); }

template<> GoalZoneFlashStyle 
Evaluator::fromString(const string &val) { return stringToGoalZoneFlashStyle(val); }

template<> Color              
Evaluator::fromString(const string &val) { return Color::iniValToColor(val); }
```

Then, in the Setting class, I replaced the similar block of code with this call:

```
DataType fromString(const string &val) { 
    return mEvaluator.fromString<DataType>(val); 
}
```

This seems to work nicely, and is pretty readable.

If anyone is interested, the full code will be available at the link below, after it is more fully tested and checked in.

https://code.google.com/p/bitfighter/source/browse/zap/Settings.h

Comment: You can not declare and moreover define member template specializations inside class declaration.

Comment: You are right... the above code compiles with VC++, but, I have since learned, not with gcc.  I'll update it with the correct code.

Comment: Don't put template code to `*.cpp` files if you want to use it in other translation units **and** you don't use explicit instantiation.